# ajax update block on click to link

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I am using [jQuery Ajax Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load) module in my site to load some contents from url to show on specific div which has a required class. With this module I am able to fetch the Page content from URL through ajax & displays on specific block. I need to replace the blocks when click on the link. for-example I have a block A displayed on content area, also I have block B & C which are hidden for now. when I click on link B the block A should be replaced with block B & so on using AJAX. 
Please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What have you already tried?
Having a look at the module JS, there is a function `jquery_ajax_load_load(el, target, url)`. Have you tried calling it?

**EDIT**
To load block content you could either use another module specifically for it (search "drupal block ajax load") ([ajax blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks)) or you could create your own module that just returns block content when navigating to a url. This should be quite easy by implementing [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and returning the value returned by [block_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7)

Comment: Its calling by itself when i activate the module, it will display the loading icon & contents fetching from URL, but my question is how i display block, as there is no URL available for blocks in drupal 7?

Comment: I will update my answer